# .load() a div from another html document using Var

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I'm trying to load a Div which is selected by a click, I save the txt from it so it can show the wanted one.

How do I tell jquery which div to load?  Here is the code.

```
$('li').click(function(){
        var selected = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        var thisone = $ ('#'+ selected);
        $('#inhere').load('secondcontent.html thisone');
        $(thisone).slideDown(200);
        $(thisone).addClass('online');
        $('.bubble').fadeIn(900).delay(2000).hide(200);
    });
    $('.close_pseudo').click(function(){
        $('.online').slideUp(200).removeClass('online');
        $('.bubble').hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be a victim of PHP-like thinking here. You need to point to a particular div like this:

```
var selected = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
var thisone = '#'+selected;
$('#inhere').load('secondcontent.html '+ thisone);
```

Comment: I tryed it out, but still not working. secondcontent.html is at the root like my index.html Do I point it right?

Comment: Then it's possible that `selected` doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: Console.log shows me the name of the div called grid, so it should be the right one..

Comment: got error -> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. What does this mean?

Comment: It means you can't use AJAX `.load` on a local filesystem. This is a feature, not a bug. It should work when you access the files through an actual webserver, though.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, your jquery code stinks like luxemburguese cheese mate °-)

`$('li').click(function(){
var selected = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

        var thisone = $ ('#'+ selected);

        $('#inhere').load('secondcontent.html thisone');

        thisone.slideDown(200).addClass('online');

        $('.bubble').fadeIn(900).delay(2000).hide(200);

    });

    $('.close_pseudo').click(function(){

        $('.online').slideUp(200).removeClass('online');

        $('.bubble').hide();

    });
`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this, I can load the Divs now, but I can't close them anymore, jquery puts the class online on an li element..

Comment: I cant load the DIV using your code, only works with $('#inhere').load('ajax/secondcontent.html #'+selected);

Comment: please post on jsfiddle.net the current your code. And don't forget to credit the SO user who helped you.

Comment: and i think `$('#inhere').load('secondcontent.html thisone'); ` should be `$('#inhere').load('secondcontent.html '+thisone); `